# How long should inserting 150K rows take in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

So I am inserting dummy data into my application.

I have insert statements that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (1, 4);
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (1, 6);
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (1, 11);
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (2, 6);
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (2, 15);
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (2, 19);
```

150,000 of them to be precise; The insertion seems to be taking it's time; but they are obviously rather simple inserts, so I am wondering How long I should expect this to take if it will take a while I will cancel the insert and change the dummy data script to generate bulk insert statements...

Local server; so other traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows at once, like:

```
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` (1, 4), (1, 6)...
```

But check out docs for you RDBMS how many records at once it can handle. Seems that 1000 will work. That'l be much faster than inserting single row per query

Answer (score 0):

Try doing them as a single INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO `submission_tagged` VALUES (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 11), ...
```